# surefire plugin does not work with jacoco plugin

Tags: maven, code-coverage, sonarqube, jacoco, test-coverage

I want to make test coverage in my project. i created profile:
my pom xml profile is:

```
    <profile>
        <id>test-coverage</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven.surefire.plugin.version}</version>
                    <configuration combine.self="override">
                        <redirectTestOutputToFile>true</redirectTestOutputToFile>
                        <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                        <argLine>
                            -Xms128m -Xmx1G -XX:MaxPermSize=128M
                        </argLine>

                           <groups>com.project.test.annotation.QuickTest</groups>

                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>0.7.1.201405082137</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>report</id>
                            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>report</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>

            </plugins>
        </build>

    </profile>
```

i am running these commands:
mvn clean install -DfailIfNoTests=false -P test-coverage
mvn sonar:sonar

and i couldnt get test coverage, what i am missing?
my sonar version: 4.3

Answer (score 2):

The main issue you encounter is the definition of the `argLine` property of surefire maven plugin which should be set as a property and not in the configuration of the plugin.
Because when you do so, the JaCoCo maven plugin can't set the argline to configure its agent.

So argLine should be define as a property in your pom.

See http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/JaCoCo+Plugin for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add a jacoco listener to the surefire plugin, e.g.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <!-- Minimal supported version is 2.4 -->
  <version>2.13</version>
  <configuration>
    <properties>
      <property>
        <name>listener</name>
        <value>org.sonar.java.jacoco.JUnitListener</value>
      </property>
    </properties>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set your argline to look like this

```
<argLine>
     ${argLine} -Xms128m -Xmx1G -XX:MaxPermSize=128M
</argLine>
```

that way when JaCoCo sets the argLine for its agent you don't override it, you just append yours to it.